# How to remove spywares from factory reset list?

Tags: applications, factory-reset, malware

I have a lenovo phone with Android in it. The phone is so infected by auto installed apps for the past few weeks that I've decided to do a factory reset. However, the factory reset happen to reinstall all of those unwanted apps (Takatap, EasyTouch, OmniSwipe, Privacy Guard etc)

Even when I uninstalled those apps before factory reset, it got installed back by the factory reset itself.

How do I remove these apps?

I've tried:
- Disable auto restore
- formatted sd card

Comment: Are they system apps, or user apps?

Comment: I'm sure it's user apps. I don't think lenovo actually install [Takatap](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.takatap.rewards&hl=en)? and a bunch of other useless auto-reinstall apps?